# Identify millipede: brown body and yellow spots on the sides

Tags: identification, pest-control, caterpillar, millipedes

There is this adult and 4-5 small ones in a [Snake Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_trifasciata) pot. It looks like [yellow spotted millipede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpaphe_haydeniana)

[image]

Is it dangerous for humans ?
Is it useful or dangerous for the plant/ soil ?

If dangerous, I'll try to add [boric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borax) to the soil to kill them. Hope it works.

Comment: Harmless. I'd use dish soap, not acid. Put outside overnight and they will leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Millipedes are detritivores, meaning that they primarily feed on decaying plant matter. They are not a danger to people or living plants. However, if you have pets and are concerned about them eating the millipede, I would recommend driving it outside.